# table row selection error in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

i am creating a table layout with radio group by dynamically adding radiobuttons to it  and i want to know  which row is selected containing the radio group   and i want to retrive the texview data also  in the same row .how can i do that any suggestion will be a great help for me.

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {
TableLayout table;
RadioGroup  mRadioGroup;
ArrayList<String> list_name;

int color_blue = -16776961;
int color_gray = -7829368;
int color_black = -16777216;
int color_white = -1;

final int CHECK_BUTTON_ID = 982301;
int ids_check[];
boolean bool_check[];


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

   list_name = new ArrayList<String>();

   list_name.add("Close");
   list_name.add("Cristiano");
   list_name.add("David");
   list_name.add("Fernando");
   list_name.add("Messi");
   list_name.add("Kaka");
   list_name.add("Wayne");

   list_name.add("use");
   list_name.add("e");
   list_name.add("eff");
   list_name.add("euyr");
   list_name.add("ejjyytuty");
   list_name.add("madre");
   list_name.add("yuir");
   list_name.add("eyrty");
   list_name.add("etytr");
   list_name.add("ewrrtt");

   bool_check = new boolean[list_name.size()];
   ids_check = new int[list_name.size()];
   createTableRows();

   }

   public void createTableRows()
   {
   for (int i = 0; i < list_name.size(); i++)
   {
   final TableRow table_row = new TableRow(this);
   TextView tv_name = new TextView(this);
   Button btn_check = new Button(this);
   ImageView img_line = new ImageView(this);

   table_row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
   table_row.setBackgroundColor(color_black);
   table_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  // table_row.setFocusable(true);

   mRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(this); 

   // test adding a radio button programmatically

   final RadioButton[] mbutton=new RadioButton[7];
   for(int l=0;l<7;l++){
       mbutton[l]=new RadioButton(this);
       mbutton[l].setText("test"+l);
       mRadioGroup.addView(mbutton[l]);

   }


 //  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
          // RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          // RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  // mRadioGroup.addView(newRadioButton);






   tv_name.setText((CharSequence) list_name.get(i));
   tv_name.setTextColor(color_blue);
   tv_name.setTextSize(30);
   tv_name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
   tv_name.setWidth(150);

   btn_check.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 30));
   btn_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_checkbox_unchecked);

   img_line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
   img_line.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.separater_line);

   table_row.addView(tv_name);
   table_row.addView(btn_check);
   table_row.addView(mRadioGroup);
   table.addView(table_row);
   table.addView(img_line);
//table.addView(mRadioGroup);

   mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup, int checkedId) {
            for(int i=0; i<mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                 RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                 int t=table.indexOfChild(table_row);
                 System.out.println(t);
                 if(btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                      String text = btn.getText().toString();
                      // do something with text
                      Log.d(text," event1");
                      return;
                 }
            }
       }
  });



   }

   }
   }
```

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? Please include details about the error you're getting (logCat with exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not using ListView ? there's nothing in the code that cannot be done by a list view?
You can add you layout by setting the custom adapter.